# Publicação de um site

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Gostaria de saber, qual o valor em média gasto para publicar um site e-commerce na internet, com banco de dados, compra de domínio e etc... e o que exatamente teria que fazer para ficar completamente no Ar. Sou estudante de Tecnologia da Informação e estou iniciando na área de programação. Se alguém puder me fornecer as informações, ficarei grato.

Comment: Não sei se este tipo de pergunta se enquadra neste site, mas mesmo que sim ela é muito abrangente. Responder esta pergunta envolveria levar em consideração uma série de fatores, seria praticamente um plano de negócios.

Comment: Você quer saber o custo apenas da hospedagem? Você pretende construir o site, e o banco de dados? Que tipo de domínio você pretende (.com, .com.br) existem diversos e com custo diferente. E reforçando o que Genos falou...

Comment: Então, é um trabalho para a faculdade que estamos desenvolvendo em Asp.Net-MVC e no final teremos que publicar o site, e estamos planejando utilizar um domínio .com.br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você primeiramente deverá comprar um domínio, que em média custa R$30,00 anuais. Depende de onde você comprar(Registro.br, GoDaddy ...)

E aí dependendo da linguagem você irá contratar um servidor para hospedar seu site (considerando que você irá contratar um serviço para isso). Como você disse que é em C# existem bastantes servidores (Locaweb, RedeHost, GoDaddy ...), cada um tem seu preço, mas a média é uns R$45,00 anuais.

Normalmente o banco de dados já vem incluso na contratação do servidor.

Comment: Entendi, então no caso eu preciso de um domínio e de um servidor, então posso considerar que o valor não ultrapassa R$100,00 ao ano certo?

Answer (score 1):

Se vc quer fazer o site em si, existem centenas de possibilidades, dominios gratuitos, etc.

Se quer simplesmente fazer um eccomerce existem plataformas facilitadoras como o [wix](http://pt.wix.com/ecommerce/loja-virtual).

Meu primo paga R$29 / ano pelo registro + R$ 19 / mês da Illuria (plataforma ecommerce)